# Scanning an array of strings for matches in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have an array of string and I want to search for a certain words (cat or dog) in each string within the array and be able to view the results in the order they came.

Example sentences

```
Strings[0] = "Subject family leans toward cats" 
Strings[1] = "Test subject prefers dogs"
```

I tried `String.each {|x| x.scan(/cat|dog)/ }` but I would only ever get the last match in the results. how might I do this correctly to get `puts $1 => cat  puts $2 => dog`? Thank you for your assistance

Comment: it's unclear the output you want. What is puts $1 => cat puts $2 => dog?

Comment: I want my first result to be cat and the second to be dog

Comment: I want to have the matches in the order they came for use later. I don't really intend on outputting it.

Comment: `String` is the class of strings. If you tried running your code example, it'd raise an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
strings = [ "Subject family leans toward cats",
            "Test subject prefers dogs" ]
cat_and_dogs = strings.join.scan /cat|dog/
#=> ["cat", "dog"]
```

so now you can `puts` it:

```
puts cats_and_dogs[0]
#=> "cat"
puts cats_and_dogs[1]
#=> "dog"
puts cats_and_dogs.join(" & ")
#=> "cat & dog"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sentences = [
  "Subject family leans toward cats",
  "Test subject prefers dogs",
]

sentences.flat_map { |s| s.scan(/dog|cat/) }
# => ["cat", "dog"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand the question but try this and see if it helps you make progress:

```
["...", "..."].map { |e| e[/cat|dog/] }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
list = ["Subject family leans toward cats.","Tes subject perfers dogs not cats"]
list.each { |x| 
    puts x.scan(/cat|dog/) 
}
```

output:

```
cat
dog
cat
```